# Selecting values that are not associated with one side of a many to many relationship

Tags: sql-server, except

I have a junction table between categories and values that indicate which categories are associated with which each value. I would like to find the values that are not associated with each category.

Category:

```
ID CategoryName
-- ------------
 1 category1
 2 category2
 3 category3
```

CategoryValue:

```
CategoryID ValueID
---------- -------
         1       1
         1       2
         2       1
         3       2
```

Value:

```
ID ValueName
-- ---------
 1 value1
 2 value2
 3 value3
```

The output I would like for the query is the following:

```
CategoryID ValueID ValueName
---------- ------- ---------
         1       3 value3
         2       2 value2
         2       3 value3
         3       1 value1
         3       3 value3
```

I'm pretty stuck on how to approach this as a query. The "junction" table seems to prevent the usual LEFT JOIN WHERE null approach. So any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need all combinations of `Category` and `Value` (a `CROSS JOIN`) except those that appear in the `CategoryValue`. This can be done with a `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

```
SELECT 
    c.CategoryID, v.ValueID, v.ValueName
FROM 
    Category AS c
  CROSS JOIN
    Value AS v
  LEFT JOIN
    CategoryValue AS cv
      ON  cv.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
      AND cv.ValueID = v.ValueID
WHERE
   cv.CategoryID IS NULL ;
```

or a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    c.CategoryID, v.ValueID, v.ValueName
FROM 
    Category AS c
  CROSS JOIN
    Value AS v
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS
     ( SELECT *
       FROM CategoryValue AS cv
       WHERE cv.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
         AND cv.ValueID = v.ValueID 
     ) ;
```

or an `EXCEPT` solution:

```
SELECT 
    c.CategoryID, v.ValueID, v.ValueName
FROM 
    Category AS c
  CROSS JOIN
    Value AS v

EXCEPT

SELECT 
    cv.CategoryID, v.ValueID, v.ValueName
FROM 
    CategoryValue AS cv
  JOIN
    Value AS v
      ON  cv.ValueID = v.ValueID ;
```